# php Login form, authenticate against another website

Tags: php, forms, authentication, action

I currently have a login form on my website, which POSTs to another web based service(web portal) that i run. This allows people to login to the web portal directly from my home page(bypassing the actual login page of the portal).
This is all working fine, except that if wrong username/password combo is entered, the form will still POST to the web portal, which then displays 'login failed'

Proposed Solution:
    Use CURL to perform a POST on the server side, and then check the responce html for the words 'Login Failed'.
    If the text 'Login Failed' is found, the login form should display an error.
    If the text 'Login Failed' is NOT found, the login form should continue to POST to the web portal.

Could someone please correct me if there is a simpler method?
Any links or snippets that could point me in the correct direction would be gratefully received.

Comment: So, my friend whose username is "Login Failed" won't be able to login in your page? :( On a more serious note, that "another website" where you are validating the usernames/passwords, should ideally provide a webservice to handle the login, where you'll have the result of the operation without having to parse the resulting HTML. Also, what happens if the website changes language or wording (e.g. "username or password incorrect")?

Comment: Unfortunately the web portal is part of a software package that we purchsed, and are unable to make any modifications to it.

Comment: The login error message is a little more detailed, i just simplified it above. If we upgrade the software and the wording changes, i'll have to change the code on my website.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `curl_error()` will return suitable code?